# Regular expression derivation for the knob movement

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have the following question regarding a situation given and we are then required to derive a regular expression out of it.

[image]

What i have to do now i to give a regular expression for this language described by the knob movement from A,B and C. Because i have to go through B if i were to traverse to C, and vice versa, i know that B must be present as part of the expression.

Here's what i attempted:

ABC U ABA U BAB U BCB U CBA U CBC

Simplifying it:

AB(C U A) U B(AB U CB) U CB(A U C)

I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing it right as I find out that I'm brute forcing. I'm terrible at deriving regular expressions so I'll appreciate some corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression won't capture short sequences (for example a single `A`), or repeated letters.

I think negative lookahead is the simplest way to write this. The allowed transitions are:

- A not followed by C: `A(?!C)`
- B anywhere: `B`
- C not followed by A: `C(?!A)`

Combining these rules:

```
(A(?!C)|B|C(?!A))+
```